# Criar trigger para sequence em primary key

Tags: oracle

Tenho a seguinte tabela no oracle:

table hospede

```
id_hospede  
nome  
login  
senha  
rg  
cpf  
telefone
```

sequência:

```
create sequence seq_hospede_1
start with 1
increment by 1
maxvalue 1000
minvalue 1
nocache
cycle;
```

trigger:

```
CREATEOR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir  
BEFORE INSERTON hospede  
FOR EACH ROWBEGINSELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL  
INTO:new.id  
FROM dual;  
END;
```

Só não consigo criar a trigger. A sequência já está criada. Como eu crio a trigger relacionada com o `id_hospede` para incrementar no momento do `insert`?

Answer (score 2):

Qual é a tua versão Oracle? Se for 12c, existe agora identiy column, que faz o incremento por ti, sem triggers, nem sequencias:

```
CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab (
  id          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Se não tiveres 12c, não vejo o que é que o trigger tem de mal. Dá erro?

Já agora, experimente este código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir  
BEFORE INSERT ON hospede  
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   :new.id  :=  dept_seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Comment: eu só não sei como eu referencio o id_hospede para fazer o auto increement no momento do insert.

Comment: No primeiro exemplo que dei, não referencias a coluna: insert into identity_test_tab(description) values('teste');

Comment: desculpa, esqueci de me referir ao trecho. Estou falando do setundo trecho da sua resposta, que fala do nextval. Coloca um exemplo completo da insersão no id_hospede, nome, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde André,

A sequence já age como uma trigger. Na hora do insert vc pode chamar passando o nextval no values:

```
INSERT INTO nomeTabela (seq_hospede_1) VALUES (seq_hospede_1.nextval);
```

Comment: não entendi. Eu uso sec_hospdede_1 nextval no momento do insert? Dá um exemplo, favor.

Comment: INSERT INTO nomeTabela (seq_hospede_1)
VALUES (seq_hospede_1.nextval);

Answer (score -1):

Para as versões sem o identity

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir  
BEFORE INSERTON hospede  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
 if :new.id is null then
   :new.id := dept_seq.NEXTVAL;
 end if;  
END;
```

A vantagem aqui é permitir uma insersão informando a chave , registros legados de sistemas anteriores por exemplo.